# Conditional method execution in a class instance

Tags: python, functional-programming, monads

I want to create monad that is able to handle mathematical errors gracefully.  I created something like:

```
from enum import Enum

class Monad(Enum):
    Safe = 1
    Fail = 2

class DivisionMonad:
    def __init__(self, value=None, type=Monad.Safe):
        self.value = value
        self.type = type

    def __truediv__(self, val):
        if self.type == Monad.Fail:
            return DivisionMonad(type=Monad.Fail)
        try:
            return DivisionMonad(self.value / val)
        except:
            return DivisionMonad(type=Monad.Fail)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'< {self.value} >'


d = DivisionMonad(1)
d = d / 3
print(d.value)
print(d.type)
d = d / 0
print(d.value)
print(d.type)
```

But I believe this could be simpler by making the class use different methods based on the state of the Monad.  Is there a way to create `conditional` execution of methods based on an `instance` attribute other than `if/else` statements?

Comment: This isn't a monad. It's just a class that accomplishes one task that monads can be used to accomplish.

Comment: that's a fair point, I'm just trying to mimic that behavior

Comment: At the very least, `__truediv__` still should return a `DivisionMonad` regardless of the state of its arguments.

Comment: that's a good point, i'll update

Comment: Should `DivisionMonad` instance change **its  own** state? If yes, you can use [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Otherwise it is better to write 2 **different** classes with different behaviour.